# Kafka producer fails to produce message via Bootstrap server. how to set broker host?

Tags: java, apache-zookeeper, kafka-producer-api

Getting timeout Exception with Kafka Producer API.

Manual process of Producing Kafka Message

We SSH to kafka Server: x.x.x.x
Over there we enter below command for producer

```
/kafka/bin/kafka-console-producer.sh --broker BrokerHostAddress:9092 --topic TestTopic
{ValidJsonData}
```

Kafka server and BrokerHostAddress are different address.

Trying to produce message on above topic via Java + kafka-clients (2.1.0)
getting : 
java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: org.apache.kafka.common.errors.TimeoutException: Failed to update metadata after 60000 ms.

````
String bootstrap_Server = "x.x.x.x:port"
private static KafkaProducer<String, String> producer = null;
Properties props = new Properties();
props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrap_Server);
props.put(ProducerConfig.CLIENT_ID_CONFIG, "KafkaExampleProducer");
props.put(ProducerConfig.KEY_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(ProducerConfig.VALUE_SERIALIZER_CLASS_CONFIG, StringSerializer.class.getName());
props.put(ProducerConfig.ACKS_CONFIG, "all");
props.put(ProducerConfig.RETRIES_CONFIG, 0);
props.put(ProducerConfig.BATCH_SIZE_CONFIG, 16384);
props.put(ProducerConfig.LINGER_MS_CONFIG, 1);
producer = new KafkaProducer<String, String>(props);

kafkaInTopicName = "TestTopic";
Key = "123123";
value = "{ValidJsonData}";
producer.send(new ProducerRecord<String, String>(kafkaInTopicName, key, value)).get(); ```
````

Comment: try add Kafka portal `Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("bootstrap.servers", "localhost:9092");`

Answer (score 0):

From lines `props.put(ProducerConfig.BOOTSTRAP_SERVERS_CONFIG, bootstrap_Server);` and `String bootstrap_Server = "x.x.x.x"` it seems that your bootstrap server doesn't contain the port, so it should be "x.x.x.x:9092" where "x.x.x.x" is the IP address of one of the Kafka brokers in your cluster.

Comment: Sorry, missed to add port. 
It is there.
still I am getting error. Updated the query.